# Question on disjunctive normal form (I think this is what it is?) and its induction proof

Tags: logic, induction, proof-explanation

I have been stuck at this question for >1 week, I am self-studying so please if anyone can help I would be really grateful.

> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> $2.37(b)$: [image]

1. I am completely baffled by what the general strategy is here.
   Normally with induction one proves the base case, assume the result
   holds for $n$ and proves it holds for $n+1$.

   That doesn't seem like what he is doing here: there are both $n$ and
   $m$ that we need to deal with, he SEEMS to have done induction on
   $n$, but not $m$. (I say 'seems', because I am not sure what he has actually done with $n$ either)
2. What is he doing when he used the induction hypothesis in the 2nd
   pic? The normal induction hypothesis as I understand is to assume
   the result holds for $n$, and then one will proceed to show the same
   holds for $n+1$. However he didn't seem to make such hypothesis here
   (in fact I am not sure if he even made any), so what is he using
   exactly?
3. In the 3rd pic under the $*$ theorem, he replaced the conjunction
   shorthand $\theta$ with $\psi$ (where he replaced $n$ with $m$).
   What is he doing there and how is that a legit move? Surely that
   conjunction sign was supposed to apply to $\theta$ only and not
   anything else.
4. If I understand correctly, the RHS of the result is just
   $(\theta_1\land\theta_2\land...\theta_n)\lor(\psi_1\land\psi_2\land...\psi_n)$,
   which is exactly what LHS abbreviates to. If so, why bother doing an
   induction? If two sides are the same formula surely their truth
   values necessarily equal to each other. Can't we just expand both sides to show they are the same?

Comment: The RHS of the result is $$\begin{align}&&(\theta_1\lor\psi_1)\land(\theta_1\lor\psi_2)\land\cdots&\land(\theta_1\lor\psi_m)\\&\land&(\theta_2\lor\psi_1)\land(\theta_2\lor\psi_2)\land\cdots&\land(\theta_2\lor\psi_m)\\ &\land&\cdots&\land(\theta_n\lor\psi_m)\end{align}$$ The theorem proves binary left distributivity of $\lor$ over $\land$ can be extended to an arbitrary number of conjuncts on the left. This is the first inductive proof. The "shortcut" then proves right distributivity by using commutativity of $\lor$ and the left distributivity result just proven.

Comment: @DerekElkins Thank you so much! Could you explain how one is supposed to interpret the RHS please? Because with the notation given, I am not sure how one can come to interpret RHS as $(\theta_1\lor\psi_1)\land...(\theta_1\lor\psi_m)\land(\theta_2\lor\psi_1)\land(\theta_n\lor\psi_m)$

Comment: Think of $\bigwedge$ as $\sum$ and $\lor$ as multiplication, then the equation is just $(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i)(\sum_{j=1}^m y_j)=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n x_i y_j$. The $n=m=2$ case is $(x_1+x_2)(y_1+y_2)=x_1 y_1+x_1 y_2 +x_2 y_1 + x_2 y_2$. In fact, the proof given works in *any* commutative [semiring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiring) including bounded [distributive lattices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_lattice) (which $\bot,\top,\land,\lor$ forms). The proof also works for arbitrary distributive lattices, or with a slight change for non-commutative semirings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 4 ... If so, why bother doing an induction?

- To demonstrate that an induction proof with two indices will work.

  - Though apparently it missed the mark, since it caused bafflement.
- The steps are:

  - Prove that $(\bigwedge_{i=1}^n\theta_i)\vee\phi=\bigwedge_{i=1}^n(\theta_i\vee\phi)$ holds for all integer $n\geq 1$
  - Assert that likewise: $\theta_i\vee(\bigwedge_{j=1}^m\psi_j)=\bigwedge_
    {j=1}^m(\theta_i\vee\psi_j)$ holds for all integer $m\geq 1$.
  - Substiute $\phi = (\bigwedge_{j=1}^m\psi_j)$ and put it together.
- Thus for all $n\geq 1$ and all $m\geq 1$: $$\begin{align}(\bigwedge_{i=1}^n\theta_i)\vee(\bigwedge_{j=1}^m \psi_j) ~
   &=(\bigwedge_{i=1}^n\theta_i)\vee\phi &&\text{Substitution} 
  \\ &= \bigwedge_{i=1}^n(\theta_i\vee\phi)&&\text{As proven below}
  \\ &= \bigwedge_{i=1}^n(\theta_i\vee(\bigwedge_{j=1}^m\psi_j)) &&\text{Substitute back}
  \\ &= \bigwedge_{i=1}^n(\bigwedge_{j=1}^m(\theta_i\vee\psi_j)) &&\text{Similarly}
  \end{align}$$
- The induction proof is:

  - Trivially: $(\bigwedge_{i=1}^1\theta_i)\vee\phi=\theta_1\vee\phi=\bigwedge_{i=1}^1(\theta_i\vee\phi)$
  - Assuming that $(\bigwedge_{i=1}^n\theta_i)\vee\phi=\bigwedge_{i=1}^n(\theta_i\vee\phi)$, then $$(\bigwedge_{i=1}^{n+1}\theta_i)\vee\phi {=((\bigwedge_{i=1}^{n}\theta_i)\wedge\theta_{n+1})\vee\phi \\ = ((\bigwedge_{i=1}^{n}\theta_i)\vee\phi)\wedge(\theta_{n+1}\vee\phi) \\ = (\bigwedge_{i=1}^{n}(\theta_i\vee\phi))\wedge(\theta_{n+1}\vee\phi)\\ =\bigwedge_{i=1}^{n+1}(\theta_i\vee\phi)}$$
  - Therefore demonstrating what was to be proven, by induction.
- And you can use the definition that $\bigwedge_{i=1}^n \theta_i =\theta_1\wedge\cdots\wedge\theta_n$ to verify that the inductive reasoning works.

  - Hopefully giving you confidence that it works in less easy to visualise cases.

---

Comment: Thank you so much! After having read your answer I now understand how the general strat goes and cleared most of the blocking points. But I am still not too sure about what happened with $m$ - specifically the 2nd step in your answer (i.e. 'Assert that likewise..').

Comment: I am gonna take a guess: is he basically saying, ok so $(\bigwedge_{i=1}^n\theta_i)$ and $(\bigwedge_{j=1}^m\psi_j)$ are essentially the same, it's just that they have different indexes. If the induction for the former works, surely it works for the latter too. So just replace the former with the latter, and since $\phi$ can stand for any formula, just substitute it with $\theta_i$ so that the whole thing can then be substituted into $*$ to complete the proof. Is this right?

Comment: @DanielMak Indeed, that is so.

Answer (score 1):

1. It can be proven by using double induction; it applies mathematical induction for $m$ for the statement first:

> The distribution law $\left(\bigwedge_{i=1}^n \theta_i \right) \lor \left(\bigwedge_{j=1}^m \psi_i \right) \equiv \bigwedge_{i=1}^n\bigwedge_{j=1}^m (\theta_i\vee \psi_j)$ holds for all $n$.

Then it apply mathematical induction for $n$ to prove the above statement. However, the proof you have introduced *does not need the induction for $m$*. It applies the base case of mentioned statement twice.

2. It uses the induction hypothesis correctly. We assume $m=1$ in the first step, to prove the base case of the statement I have quoted. To use the inductive hypothesis he splits $\bigwedge_{i=1}^{n+1} \theta_i$ to $\bigwedge_{i=1}^n \theta_i$ and $\theta_{n+1}$ and apply the distributive law.
3. Regard $\left(\bigwedge_{j=1}^m \psi_i \right)$ as a single statement; We have proven $\left(\bigwedge_{i=1}^n \theta_i \right) \lor \phi \equiv \bigwedge_{i=1}^n (\theta_i\lor\phi)$ for any $\phi$. What he do in the proof is just replacing $\phi$ to $\left(\bigwedge_{j=1}^m \psi_i \right)$.
4. The comment by Derek Elkins answers this question partially. However, whatever the formula looks like, we shall use the induction to prove it for arbitrary natural number $n$ and $m$. You may expand it to prove the desired statement, and it is valid for *specific* $m$ and $n$. However, such a strategy makes a proof for each $m$ and $n$, and proving the distributive law for *any* $m$ and $n$ such a way generates infinitely many proofs. Mathematical induction makes possibly infinitely many proofs to a single proof.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been studying your answer for the last few days but I am still not sure about the following: 1) Could you elaborate more about what you mean by not needing induction of $m$ by applying the base case twice please? 2) Regarding $\phi$, in the 2nd pic it was used to replace $\psi_1$, whereas in the 3rd pic it was used to replace  $\left(\bigwedge_{j=1}^m \psi_i \right)$ instead, is it always meant to mean $\left(\bigwedge_{j=1}^m \psi_i \right)$, but just because in the 2nd pic $m=1$, therefore it was used to replace $\psi_1$?

Comment: @DanielMak For your first question, I mean a *base case* the case $m=1$ of the mentioned statement, so it denotes $\left(\bigwedge_{i=1}^n \theta_i \right)\land \psi \equiv \bigwedge_{i=1}^n (\theta_i\vee \psi_j)$ for all $n$.

Comment: For the second question, the latter one you proposed is right. $\phi$ is used to replace $\psi_1$ just because it treats the case $m=1$.